# Apply color to specific cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm trying to apply the color blue to a row of cells, but when I do it doesn't return an error or make any changes.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='concentrated.xlsx')
ws2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data in')

HeaderFill = PatternFill(start_color='002b43', end_color='002b43', fill_type='solid')

for cell in ws2['A3':'O3']:
        HeaderFill

wb.save('concentrated.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not actually assigning HeaderFill to anything in your loop. The correct thing to assign it to is the **fill** property of the cell.

So:

```
for row in ws2['A3':'O3']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.fill = HeaderFill
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Charlie Clark for catching my oversight: slices return row tuples, not cell tuples.

Comment: thank you, I completely missed that. But its giving me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fill'` error now.

Comment: Worksheet slices always return a tuple of rows. So you need `for row in ws['A3':'O3']: for cell in row: cell.fill = HeaderFill`